# ionic 3 build Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

I'm having trouble extracting the APK file
In Ionic
Problem is installed after installing

```
npm install --save @ ionic-native / push
```

and

```
npm install --save @ ionic-native / core @ late @ ionic-native / google-maps @ latest
```

This is a blunder

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ': app'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
  >      > All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0

This is a project.properties file

```
# Project target.
target = android-27
android.library.reference.1 = CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2 = app
cordova.system.library.1 = com.android.support: support-v4: 26. +
cordova.system.library.2 = com.android.support: appcompat-v7: 26. +
cordova.gradle.include.1 = cordova-plugin-googlemaps / sarah-tbxml-android.gradle
cordova.system.library.3 = com.google.android.gms: play-services-maps: 15.0.1
cordova.system.library.4 = com.google.android.gms: play-services-location: 15.0.1
cordova.system.library.5 = com.android.support: support-core-utils: 26.1.0
cordova.gradle.include.2 = cordova-support-google-services / sarah-build.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.3 = phonegap-plugin-multidex / sarah-multidex.gradle
cordova.system.library.6 = com.android.support: support-v13: 27. +
cordova.system.library.7 = me.leolin: ShortcutBadger: 1.1.17@aar
cordova.system.library.8 = com.google.firebase: firebase-messaging: 11.6.2
```

I hope to find a solution you have tired of this mistake

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have v15.0.1 of the Play Services library and v11.6.2 of the Firebase library. Up to v15, the Firebase and Play Services versions have to align ([see here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/versioning)).

One way you can try to do this is with a couple of plugins - [cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release) and [cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release), for example:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release  --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=12.+
cordova plugin add cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release  --variable FIREBASE_VERSION=12.+
```

These plugins will attempt to override the versions specified by other plugins to align them.

Note there are some plugins which directly reference the Google Services plugin which implicitly references the Play Services library and which these plugins are unable to override - see [caveats](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release#caveats).